# Send information from ImageView extend to MainClass

Tags: android

I have an class

```
TouchImageView extends ImageView
```

then I have in this class:

```
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            switch (event.getAction()) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //Tell main class action down
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //Tell main class action move

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                   //Tell main class action up
                    break;

            }


        }
```

in this class I have implemented onTouch function. What I need is this function will do something in my main class that uses this TouchImageView;

```
private TouchImageView touch_iv = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

Comment: use handler in this case.

Comment: @ghoshak it isnt a duplicate, he stays in one and the same activity.

Comment: @ghoshak, please read the question carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy thing: implement a `setParent(...)` method
and then call a specific function of you main class:
I assume your main class is called `Main.java`.

in `TouchImageView`:

```
...

Main parent = null;

public void setParent(Main main)
{
    parent = main;
}

...

setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch (event.getAction())
        {     
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.ActionDown(TouchImageView.this, event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.ActionMove(TouchImageView.this, event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.ActionUp(TouchImageView.this, event);
                break;
        }
    }
}

...
```

in `Main`:

```
...

    private TouchImageView touch_iv = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    touch_iv.setParent(this);

...

public void ActionDown(TouchImageView view, MotionEvent event)
{
    //handle down event "event" freom view "view"
}

public void ActionMove(TouchImageView view, MotionEvent event)
{
    //handle move event "event" freom view "view"
}

public void ActionUp(TouchImageView view, MotionEvent event)
{
    //handle up event "event" freom view "view"
}

...
```

that should work.
now you get a callback everytime when the touchimageview sends one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use an `interface` in this case.

Create an interface, let's say

```
public interface PassData {
    public void doSomethingTouchUp(); //your methods
    public void doSomethingTouchDown();
}
```

In your `TouchImageView` get a reference variable, something like

```
public PassData delagateObj;//make the ref. public, so no getter/setter needed
```

Next, in your `TouchImageView` class, replace

```
//Tell main class action down
```

with

```
delagateObj.doSomethingTouchUp(); //similar for your other method
```

Finally, in your `MainClass`, or wherever you use `TouchImageView`, 2 things are necessary: implement `PassData` and give a value to the delegateObj, then override the methods:

```
public class MainClass implements PassData {

private TouchImageView touch_iv = (TouchImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    touch_iv.delegateObj = this;

    @Override
    public void doSomethingTouchUp(){
        System.out.println("My method implemented!");
    } //your methods
}
```

Comment: I forgot one last thing: in your MainClass, where you implement the interface, you have to also give a reference to your TouchImageView class. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                progressBar.setProgress(value);
            }
        });
```

refer to this example http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/handler/android-handler-example/